# CSS underline with same with as above element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create the following look:

[image]

As you can see on this picture  even if there is some padding on the "sub" menu item the border still works.

So here is what I've attempted:

```css
.menu-ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.menu-li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
  width: 100%;
}
a {
  font-family: Titillium Web;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  color: #323232;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #DB091C;
}
.sub-menu-ul {
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
}
.sub-menu-li {
  padding: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
}
hr.solid {
  border-top: 3px solid #bbb;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav style="width: 300px">
        <ul class="menu-ul">
            <li class="menu-li">
            <a href="" >Title </a> 
            <span style="float: right"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>

              <div style="display: block">
               <ul class="sub-menu-ul">
                  <li class="sub-menu-li"> <a href="#">
                        Sub menu item2
                  </a>
        <span style="float: right"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
                  </li>
                  </li>
                  <li class="sub-menu-li"> <a href="#">
                        Sub menu item2
                  </a>
 
                  </li>
               </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-li"><a href="" >Title 2</a>

            </li>
            <li class="menu-li"><a href="" >Title 2</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

But I can't seem to get the border right.

Comment: Did you try using JS accordions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I have changed the padding for `menu-li` and width of `sub-menu-li`

```
.menu-li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
  width: 100%;
}
.sub-menu-li {
  padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
}
```

Comment: Hey mate this worked one question thought i have some icons at the sub menu level how can i ensure that those align with the top let me edit my post to match it

Comment: @MarcRasmussen do u mean the `>` icon?

Comment: Balju yep thats the one

Comment: add a span tag after your anchor tag like this `<a href="#">Sub menu item2</a><span>></span>` and the css for it `span{float: right;}`